# how to have handlers in a different file in tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I want to structure my tornado project in small pieces of code. For the moment is just a small application so it is structured in 2 files core.py and handlers.py.

in handlers.py i have : all handlers  classes and a list which contains the declaraions of the handlers :

HANDLERS = [(r"/", indexHandler), (r"/listall/", listAllHandler), (r"/check/", checkPersonHandler), (r"/delete/", deleteHandler), ]

and in th core i have :

handlers = handlers.HANDLERS

well when i run my application i have an error saying "Undefined name 'indexHandler'" ?! what am i doing wrong ? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When do you define your `indexHandler` and other handlers? 
I suppose they are defined in `index.py`, then try this:

```
from index import indexHandler, listAllHandler, checkPersonHandler, deleteHandler
HANDLERS = [(r"/", indexHandler), (r"/listall/", listAllHandler), (r"/check/", checkPersonHandler), (r"/delete/", deleteHandler), ]
handlers = handlers.HANDLERS
```

Comment: Actually they are defined in the same file (handlers.py) that is why i find the error weird !

Comment: @ader277 I guess you should first define indexHandler, listAllHandler before define `HANDLERS`